# Docker container's ports clashing with nginx that is not inside container

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, server, reverse-proxy

I have a docker-compose.yml as follows setup at my root. For context, I have a Ghost CMS blog hosted on a Digital Ocean droplet. I want to install Commento using Docker (an open source commenting solution), but as I'm routing my traffic through Cloudflare DNS, I **require SSL** on both the server side and the frontend side.

However, I installed Ghost through Digital Ocean's one click Ghost setup, which configured nginx to be the reverse proxy for my site. Nginx is NOT in the container (installed on server). Nginx listens on port 80 and 443. When I try docker-compose up, it says the following error:

```
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use
```

Traefik cannot listen on the same ports at nginx (which is not within the container, but installed on the server itself). How can I fix this problem, and have my commento server reverse proxied through SSL as well? My docker-compose is as below:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  proxy:
    restart: always
    image: traefik
    command:
    - "--api"
    - "--entrypoints=Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https"
    - "--entrypoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS"
    - "--defaultentrypoints=http,https"
    - "--acme"
    - "--acme.storage=/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
    - "--acme.entryPoint=https"
    - "--acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=http"
    - "--acme.onHostRule=true"
    - "--acme.onDemand=false"
    - "--acme.email=changeme@example.com" # TODO: Replace with your email address
    - "--docker"
    - "--docker.watch"
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    - ./traefik/acme:/etc/traefik/acme
    networks:
    - web
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    labels:
    - "traefik.enable=false"

  server:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/commento/commento:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      COMMENTO_ORIGIN: https://commento.example.com # TODO: Replace commento.example.com with your domami$      COMMENTO_PORT: 8080
      COMMENTO_POSTGRES: postgres://postgres:passwordexample@db:5432/commento?s$      
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - db_network
      - web
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: commento
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: examplepassword #TODO: Replace STRONG_PASSWORD with th$    networks:
      - db_network
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data_volume:

networks:
  web:
      external
  db_network:
```

Here is my nginx server config under available sites:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/ghost/system/nginx-root; # Used for acme.sh SSL verification (https://acme.sh)

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/example.com/fullchain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/example.com/example.com.key;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;

    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

Sorry, kind of new to this. Thank you!

Comment: you will need to use a different port for nginx or the traefik-service e.g. `- "4443:443"`

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose.yml

```
...
ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
...
```

nginx/conf

```
...
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
...
```

Nginx used HOST port 443, so you cannot reuse it on your docker-compose, you must another one that is free.